# Sort multidimensional array of objects in columns

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
var arr = [
[ {'value': 3, 'id': 'ab'},  {'value': 1, 'id': 'ab'},  {'value': 5, 'id': 'ab'} ],
[ {'value': 6, 'id': 'bc'},  {'value': 3, 'id': 'bc'},  {'value': 4, 'id': 'bc'} ],
[ {'value': 1, 'id': 'cd'},  {'value': 3, 'id': 'cd'},  {'value': 2, 'id': 'de'} ],
]
```

I have an array arr. 
arr[0], arr[1] and arr[2] all contain the same amount of objects.

I would like to sort the complete array by arr[1]. For example

```
var result = [
[ {'value': 1, 'id': 'ab'},  {'value': 5, 'id': 'ab'}, {'value': 3, 'id': 'ab'}, ],
[ {'value': 3, 'id': 'bc'},  {'value': 4, 'id': 'bc'}, {'value': 6, 'id': 'bc'}, ],
[ {'value': 3, 'id': 'cd'},  {'value': 2, 'id': 'de'}, {'value': 1, 'id': 'cd'}, ],
]
```

-> arr[1] is now sorted by 'value' (3,4,6). The corresponding values in arr[0] and arr[2] were 'sorted' as well. If arr[1][1] moves to the beginning because of arr[1] being sorted correctly, so does arr[0][1] and arr[2][1].

Before sort

```
3 1 5
6 3 4
1 3 2
```

After sort

```
1 5 3 <- 1 is 'linked' to 3 in 2nd row, 5 is 'linked' to 4 in 2nd row, etc.
3 4 6 <- sorted
3 2 1 <- 3 is 'linked' to 3 in 2nd row, 2 is 'linked' to 4 in 2nd row, etc.
```

E.g. I can sort arr[1] by using

```
arr[1].sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.value-b.value
});
```

but of course this doesn't change arr[0] and arr[2] as I would like. Obviously the same is true for

```
arr.forEach(item =>
item.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.value-b.value
}));
```

which only sorts every array separately.

Is is possible e.g. to get the indices of a and b so I can move the items in arr[0] and arr[1] myself?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What does "sort by e.g. the second row" mean? How do you sort by a row? I don't see any sorting in the above at all. I see moving the second column to the first column, but...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: By row did you mean column, which is 'id'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that first calculates the sort order of the objects.
Then uses that sort order to sort each row the same way.

```js
var arr = [
  [ {'value': 3, 'id': 'ab'}, {'value': 1, 'id': 'ab'}, {'value': 5, 'id': 'ab'} ],
  [ {'value': 6, 'id': 'bc'}, {'value': 3, 'id': 'bc'}, {'value': 4, 'id': 'bc'} ], 
  [ {'value': 1, 'id': 'cd'}, {'value': 3, 'id': 'cd'}, {'value': 2, 'id': 'de'} ]
];

function sortArrayColumnsByIndex(arr2dOfObj, rowindex, objkey) {
    let rownum = rowindex || 0;
    let key = objkey || Object.keys(arr2dOfObj[0][0])[0];
    let sortorder = arr2dOfObj[rownum]
         .map((x,i)=>[x,i])
         .sort((a, b) => a[0][key] < b[0][key] ? -1 : a[0][key] > b[0][key] ? 1 : 0) 
         .map(x=>x[1]);

    arr2dOfObj.forEach( 
       (row, idx) => {
       let sorted = [];
       sortorder.forEach( (y) => {
         sorted.push(row[y]);
       })
       arr2dOfObj[idx] = sorted;
      }
  );
}

sortArrayColumnsByIndex(arr, 1, 'value');

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution but I transpose the array, then sort it and then transpose it back to it original form.

```
// sort array accordingly to this row
let i = 1;

var arr = [
[ {'value': 1, 'id': 'ab'},  {'value': 6, 'id': 'ab'},  {'value': 3, 'id': 'ab'} ],
[ {'value': 3, 'id': 'bc'},  {'value': 1, 'id': 'bc'},  {'value': 4, 'id': 'bc'} ],
[ {'value': 2, 'id': 'cd'},  {'value': 1, 'id': 'cd'},  {'value': 8, 'id': 'cd'} ],
]

function transpose(m) {
    return Object.keys(m[0]).map(function(a) {
        return m.map(function(b) { return b[a]; });
    });
}

arr = transpose(arr);

arr.sort(function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[i].value === b[i].value) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[i].value < b[i].value) ? -1 : 1;
    }
})

arr = transpose(arr);

console.log(arr);
```